# Ajax post was received, but success is not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a datatable with suppliers. The last column has a delete button that opens a modal for confirming to delete the supplier:

Delete button:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="modalActivator" value="{{supp['supplierId']}}" name="{{supp['navn']}}" data-target="#deleteConfirmModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">    
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">You are about to delete:<br /></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to continue?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" id="modal-delete" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Delete supplier</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

By clicking the button “modal-delete” there is sent a ajax post to a url: /supplier/remove, where the supplier is removed from the database.
The data is received on the url and showed in the console, but the ajax success is not fired.

I tried to change the dataType to text, but it still not fired. In the Chrome Network tool the post stands as pending

```
$('#modal-delete').click(function(e) {

  var data = {};
  data.supplierId = idToDelete;
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(){ajax_success('I was posted!');},
    error: function(){console.log('nothing was posted with ajax');},
    url: '../api/supplier-list/remove',
    cache: false
  });

});
function ajax_success(mytext) {
  console.log(mytext);
}
```

Chrome network tool:

> General
>   Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/supplier-list/remove?callback=jQuery220026602954184636474_1456116313463
>   Request Headers
>   Provisional headers are shown
>   Accept:text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Origin: localhost:8080
>   Referer: /localhost:8080/api/supplier-list
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
>   X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
>   Query String Parameters
>   callback:jQuery220026602954184636474_1456116313463
>   Form Data
>   supplierId:5

Comment: why " dataType: "text" ?

Comment: What about remove script? IS he return something? Try change dataType to JSON

Comment: Look at node js console, to approve what data is received

Comment: try to remove  dataType: "text" and check it once

Comment: I have tried both, dataType: 'text' and dataType: 'json'
In both cases the data received is: { supplierId: '5' }
I have another ajax post on another site, almost identical, and I post successfully with text. The validation of the object, failes on jsonlint.com because there are not quotes on supplierId.
The differences from the other ajax post that works and this one is that this one is launched from a modal and the other one from at dropdown onchange

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I made this mistake because I am very new to ajax and nodejs.

The data was send and received. What I did not know was that I have to make a response from the file that received the data.
This was the code from the url: api/supplier-list/remove:

```
apiRouter.post('/supplier-list/remove/', function(req,res) {
  console.log(' I got it!! ' + req.body.supplierId);
});
```

As soon as I added the last line to the code, the success function of the ajax was fired:

```
apiRouter.post('/supplier-list/remove/', function(req,res) {
  console.log(' I got it!! ' + req.body.supplierId);
  res.json('Data was found');
});
```